# Is there a way to filter out ButterKnife ViewBinding files from "CMD+SHIFT+O" (go to file) search results?

Tags: android, android-studio, butterknife, android-viewbinder

I tend to search project files in Android Studio with **CMD+SHIFT+O** shortcut because it gives all project related files instead of **Double Shift** searching through all existing files in the SDK (as far as I know).

However, I haven't found a way to filter out **ViewBinding** files that ButterKnife creates. The thing is, **ViewBinding** files always appear on top of the file I am looking for. 
[image]

Is there a way to exclude them from **cmd+shift+o** search result?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a scope to filter searches like this.
[image: Open Find path]
[image: Create your custom scope]
Type this snippet to Pattern to avoid generatedJava appears from find path

```
!file:*intermediates*/&&!file:*generated*/&&!lib:*..*
```

I think it should be work, coz it works for me... 
[image]

Comment: I tried your method, but still those files show up. I want to filter our those files when I do "Enter File Name" search (shortcut **cmd+shift+o**).

Comment: make sure when in find path mode, you immediately switch to the scope tab and have chosen the name of the scope that was created earlier

Comment: Oh, it looks like you are looking for files via Ctrl + N (in Windows), everything I do is the same as Ctrl + Shift + F, for searching. Too bad to my knowledge that can only be done with Ctrl + Shift + F or Command + Shift + O on Mac

Comment: you mean that filtering can only be done to ctrl+shift+f? wheeee.... but thanks though :)

Comment: ya, because the search file (Ctrl+N) I did still shows the file generated Java, but the result is very little so it doesn't matter.